# Modifying static property of a component doesn't re-render all of its instances in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started learning ReactJS, and I came across 'Modifying properties of components'. It said that whenever we modify a property, it calls the 'render' method to display those changes. This was fine.

Then I thought if I make the component's property static, then if I update it, it should re-render all the instances of that component. But it didn't.

Here is what I tried:

```js
class Numbers extends Component {
    static num = Math.random();

    static changeNumber() {
        num = Math.random();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={ Numbers.changeNumber }>Numbers.num</button>
        );
    }
}
```

And then, I have used this component as follows:

```js
let component = (
    <div>
        <Numbers />
        <Numbers />
        <Numbers />
    </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('something'));
```

But when I click on any button, only its content changes. Other buttons still have the old number. How do I make React to re-render all the component's instances, if there is a change in the static variable?

Comment: I doubt this example will work. Can you provide codepen for this? React don't reacts for instance variable changes. You should use state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the `properties` meaning. They are not the properties of a class (in general meaning). You can think about them as function variables. Each React component is transpiled to the function call. `<Component />` becomes `createElement(Component, props, children)`. Here is `props` are your properties you are looking for.

Props come from the parent component. To make the component rerender by himself, you should use `state`. So your example becomes:

```
class Numbers extends Component {
    state = {num: Math.random()}

    changeNumber = () => {
        this.setState({num: Math.random()});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={ this.changeNumber }>{this.state.num}</button>
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to update all child components you should add a state to the parent component.

```
class Component extends Component {
    state = {num: Math.random()}

    changeNumber = () => {
        this.setState({num: Math.random()});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Numbers onClick={ this.changeNumber }>{this.state.num}</Numbers>
        );
    }
}

function Numbers (props) {
  return <div onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</div>
}
```